# In Python how would I rename an image within a sub-folder based on the name of that sub-folder?

Tags: python, loops, file-rename

So say I have 15 folders:

- 1.Folder-A
- 2.Folder-B
- ...
- 15.Folder-N

And folder has in it 100 sub-folders:

- 1.SubFolderA-5682
- 2.SubFolderA-5683
- ...
- 100.SubFolderA-N

Then each sub-folder has in it 2 images (all images are named the exact same thing in each sub folder):

- 1.Img_one.GIF
- 2.Img_two.PNG

How would I re-name my Img_one say to the sub-folder name it is stored in? This is because as I said, the name of the images are the same in every sub-folder so I can't extract them all as the would all look like dupes.

I need to be able to:

1. Go into a folder, go into the sub-folder, then re-name each image to the name of that sub-folder. So, Img_one in SubFolder-5683 would get called A-5683
2. I think I need two loops, one to loop through all the sub-folders to re-name the images inside and another to loop through each folder the sub-folders are contained within.

I have looked all over and the only info I can find is for images in a folder and not a folder within another one so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

Answer (score 0):

Goes without saying that you should make a backup of the folder structure and images before executing this in the event that something goes wrong. You could use `os.walk` to automate the loops however I thought it best to show each step and allow you to improve it if you wish.

```
def rename(root):
    # MAKE A BACKUP FIRST.........
    if not os.path.exists(root):
        return
    for folder in os.listdir(root):  # Root folders -> A, B, C, ...N
        sub_folder_path = os.path.join(root, folder)
        for sub_folder in os.listdir(sub_folder_path):  # SubFolders A5682, etc....
            image_path = os.path.join(sub_folder_path, sub_folder)
            for i, image in enumerate(os.listdir(image_path)):  # Each image in path -> A/A5682/img1.png, ... N/Nxxxx/img2.png
                cur_image = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_path, image)
                f_type = cur_image.split("\\")[-1].split(".")[-1]  # Extract the file type, .png
                new_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_path, f"{sub_folder}-{i}.{f_type}")
                # Build new image name based on sub_folder -> A5682, the image index 1, or 2, and the f_type .png
                os.rename(cur_image, new_name)
```